# Apache Thrift : Python server with Javascript client

Tags: javascript, python, thrift

I'm currently using Apache Thrift for an API project.

I started with a little test project in order to understand how Thrift works. So, I would like to use a python server with a browser-based javascript Client.

I've read the documentation entirely, but I still have an issue I can't resolve :( :

[image: Error with google chrome inspector]

Server output :

```
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Dec/2018 17:04:34] code 501, message Unsupported method ('OPTIONS')
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Dec/2018 17:04:34] "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1" 501 -
```

**test.thrift**

```
enum Modulation
{
  BPSK
  QPSK
  APSK16
  APSK32
}

struct Coordinate {
  1: i32 X,
  2: i32 Y
}

struct Constellation {
  1: string name,
  2: i32 timestamp,
  3: list<Coordinate> coordinates
}

service Dealer
{
  Constellation getConstellation()

  Modulation getModulation()
  void setModulation(1: Modulation new_modulation)
  i32 getTimestamp()
}
```

**server.py**

```
import glob
import sys
sys.path.append('gen-py')

from TApp import Dealer
from TApp.ttypes import *

from thrift.transport import TSocket
from thrift.transport import TTransport
from thrift.protocol import *
from thrift.server import TServer, THttpServer

import time

class DealerHandler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.modulation = Modulation.BPSK

    def getConstellation(self):
        c = Constellation()
        c.name = "Test"
        c.timestamp = self.getTimestamp()
        c.coordinates = []

        return c

    def getModulation(self):
        return self.modulation

    def setModulation(self, new_modulation):
        self.modulation = new_modulation

    def getTimestamp(self):
        return int(str(time.time()).split('.')[0])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    handler = DealerHandler()
    processor = Dealer.Processor(handler)

    port = 9090
    host = '127.0.0.1'

    # HTTP SERVER
    tfactory = TTransport.TBufferedTransportFactory()
    pfactory = TJSONProtocol.TJSONProtocolFactory()
    # List of all protocols : https://thrift-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/thrift-stack.html

    #server = TServer.TSimpleServer(processor, transport, tfactory, pfactory)
    server = THttpServer.THttpServer(processor, (host, port), pfactory)
    server.serve()
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div id="timestamp" style="margin:auto; width:70%; padding:15px; text-align:center; border:1px solid black;">
    No Value
  </div>
  <br />
  <button type="button" name="button" class="btn btn-info" style="width:100%" onclick="update_timestamp()">Start connection</button>
</body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>


<script src="thrift.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="test_types.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="Dealer.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function update_timestamp() {
    var transport = new Thrift.TXHRTransport("http://localhost:9090");
    var protocol  = new Thrift.TJSONProtocol(transport);

    var client = new DealerClient(protocol);
    var val = client.getTimestamp();

    document.getElementById("timestamp").innerHTML = val;
}
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: What about these CORS errors?